# How to copy images at "play dist"?

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.2

I have a folder under `app/assets/images` that I want to copy to `public` at `play dist`. I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
val copyAssets = taskKey[Unit]("publishes the files")
val copyAssetsTask = copyAssets <<= (baseDirectory, resourceManaged in Compile, streams) map {
      (base, resources, s) =>
        s.log.info(s"resourceManaged: $resources")
        IO.copyDirectory ( base / "assets" / "images", "target"/ "scala-2.10" / "resource_managed" / "main" / "public" );
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you put `app/images` under `app/assets` instead so the images are copied out of the box by `play dist`?

Comment: I edited it. It should be app/assets/images. Play won't copy automatically.

Comment: Ah, right! images are static (not dynamic) so no need to have them there - there's nothing play could do more than copy it to `public`. Why don't you put them to `public/images`?

Comment: I have a separate project called play-web to keep all static files under /app/asset including js files. So I can tell nginx redirect static asset request to /app/assets in the run time for the development server.